# ORA-00904:"MAY":INVALID IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
INSERT INTO FCR.TRANSACTION (   
TRX_UNIT,    
TRX_DATE,    
TRX_USR,    
TRX_USR_SN,    
TRANSACTION_CODE,    
PRODUCT_CODE,    
CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION,    
AMOUNT_FC,    
EXCHANGE_RATE,    
AMOUNT_DC) 
SELECT    
SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE,    
to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    
USER_CODE,    
USER_TRANSACTION_SERIAL_NUMBER,    
TRANSACTION_CODE,    
PROFITS_PRODUCT_CODE,    
SHORT_DESCRIPTION,    
SOURCE_AMOUNT_FC,    
SOURCE_EXCHANGE_RATE,    
SOURCE_AMOUNT_EUR 
FROM    
FCR_TRANSACTION 
WHERE    
TRANSACTION_DATE = to_char(02-MAY-2006, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The above is the query which I am entering in ORACLE but it is giving me the error ORA-00904:"MAY":INVALID IDENTIFIER 
Can anyone help me with this please. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using to_char in the where clause a field called TRANSACTION_DATE  should be of type DATE not CHAR/VARCHAR

Answer (score 6):

If TRANSACTION_DATE is a date (and I sincerely hope it is) you need to use TO_DATE to convert a string into a DATE.  And because it's a string it needs to be in quotes, because that's what we do with literals.

Oh, and the other thing is, the mask needs to match the format used in the string to represent the date.

So, the line should be:

```
TRANSACTION_DATE = to_date('02-MAY-2006', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Comment: note: you do not always need to match the mask to the format.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add quotes around 02-MAY-2006, otherwise that looks like an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
TRANSACTION_DATE = to_char('02-MAY-2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Put it in quotes, otherwise it is interpeted as an identifier, not a literal.

Comment: that will give an invalid number !

Answer (score 2):

if you must use a string

To reformat you must first convert it to a date, and then to the format you desire e.g:

```
TRANSACTION_DATE = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02-MAY-2006'),'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

simply trying to reformat it as dd/mm/yyyy will not work

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = to_date('02-MAY-2006', 'dd-MON-yyyy')` instead of `WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = to_char(02-MAY-2006, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`